# Type a property/variable that accepts the ref of a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, typing

I want to type `this.engine` property with `GameEngine`
something like, `engine: GameEngine;`
and but it causes error `Property 'stop' does not exist on type 'GameEngine'`
when using a `GameEngine` `stop()` method like below

Is this even possible? Or does it make sense?

```
export default class Game extends React.PureComponent {
  engine: GameEngine;
  // engine: any; // this one works ofcourse
  
  //...

  pause() {
    this.engine.stop()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GameEngine
        ref={(ref) => { this.engine = ref; }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this `GameEngine` type is defined by you? Are you using and external framework?

Comment: it is react-native-game-engine component

Comment: Well if this react-native-game-engine component doesn't have a stop method on it it's gonna give you an error. If you provide this stop function, add an interface to GameEngine, that defines stop method?

Comment: it has stop method

Comment: https://github.com/bberak/react-native-game-engine/blob/master/src/GameEngine.js check this

Comment: Yea i was looking at that and as you know it's written with JS without providing the `types` or any interface. Couple of options here, you can define it yourself, you can define and make a PR on github =)

Comment: Oh i just saw there is actaully a types file on root. https://github.com/bberak/react-native-game-engine/blob/master/react-native-game-engine.d.ts

Comment: so what i'm gonna do then?

Comment: add an interface to GameEngine with stop function =)

Comment: okay thanks for the idea